# Copy constructor of "struct atomic"

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have the following code:

```
enum class State : uint32_t
{
    FREE,
    IDLE,
    COAST,
    MOVE,
    STOP
};

std::atomic<State> car1_state = State::IDLE;  <--- Line a
std::atomic<State> car2_state(State::IDLE);   <--- Line b
```

Following is snippet from the atomic header file:

```
// c++ header file - atomic
template<typename _Tp>
  struct atomic
  {
  private:
    _Tp _M_i;

  public:
    atomic() noexcept = default;
    ~atomic() noexcept = default;
    atomic(const atomic&) = delete;                <--- Line c
    atomic& operator=(const atomic&) = delete;
    atomic& operator=(const atomic&) volatile = delete;

    constexpr atomic(_Tp __i) noexcept : _M_i(__i) { }    <--- Line d

    operator _Tp() const noexcept
    { return load(); }

    operator _Tp() const volatile noexcept
    { return load(); }

    _Tp
    operator=(_Tp __i) noexcept
    { store(__i); return __i; }
....
```

I have a few questions:

- Line *b* compiles fine.  My understanding constructor in Line *d* is called.  Right?
- Line *a* fails compilation.  Per the error message, copy constructor in Line *c* is called, hence the error message "use of deleted function" (which I understand).

Can someone please help me understand why/how Line *a* ends up calling Line *c* (and not Line *d*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy-initialization requires an accessible, non-explicit copy or move constructor, since it formally initializes a variable from a temporary prvalue of the same type. That is,

```
Foo a = x;
```

is equivalent to:

```
Foo a = Foo(x);
```

Your type doesn't have an accessible copy constructor, hence the error. By contrast, direct-initialization does not require a copy constructor:

```
Foo a(x);
```

Comment: Thank you.  When you say "Foo a = Foo(x);"  are the following sequence of calls being made : Foo constructor (with x as param), Foo copy constructor (with reference to the temp object).   Also, just curious since Foo(x) is temporary (prvalue), why isn't move constructor called?  or is it?

Comment: @AhmedA: The copies are not required to actually be made, but a suitable constructor has to be accessible formally. Yes, either copy or move constructor are fine.

Comment: Just to clear and pedantic, is Foo(x) causing the error or Foo a = <temp object>?  I am guessing the latter, as that is the point where the copy constructor is being invoked, which happens to be marked deleted.

Comment: Copy-initialization doesn't precisely require an accessible copy constructor, it requires that construction from an rvalue is well-formed. A move constructor suffices even in the absence of a copy constructor.

Comment: @Casey: Thanks, that's a good way of putting it, or perhaps even "must be implicitly convertible from an rvalue".

Answer (score 2):

It's the difference between direct initialisation and copy initialisation. Let's generalise it:

```
A a1 = b;
A a2(b);
```

If the type of `b` is `A`, the two lines are identical. They will both call the copy constructor of `A`.

However, if the type of `b` is different from `A`, their semantics differ as well. `a2` is initialised by *direct initialisation,* which calls the appropriate constructor of `A` taking the type of `b`.

`a1`, on the other hand, is initialised by *copy initialisation,* which works as "initialise a temporary object from the argument, and then use the copy constructor to copy that temporary into the final object." So in such case, the copy initialisation is equivalent to this:

```
A a1(A(b));
```

In your case, this fails, since the copy constructor is deleted and there is no move constructor.

And to fully answer your second question, it does not call Line *c* **instead of** Line *d,* but **in addition to** Line *d.*